# Multiple file uploader in Laravel 6: "must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile, array given"

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-6

### What I have

I created a very simple multiple image uploader in Laravel 6. The code of the view and the controller are the following:

**View:**

```
<form action="{{ route('create') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input name="images[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
function create(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'images.*' => 'image',
    ]);

    foreach($request->images as $image) {
        // $filename = 'IMG_1921.jpg'
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

        // $path = 'uploads/IMG_1921.jpg'
        $path = $image->storeAs('uploads', $filename);

        // $absolutePath = 'C:\htdocs\laravel-test\storage/uploads/IMG_1921.jpg'
        $absolutePath = sprintf('%s/%s', storage_path(), $path);

        // crash here
        // $data = getimagesize($absolutePath); 
    }

    return 'ok';
}
```

### The problem

All works fine until I uncomment the line of the `getimagesize($absolutePath)` function. I also tried with `filesize($absolutePath)` and the same error is given:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Facade\FlareClient\Context\RequestContext::Facade\FlareClient\Context{closure}()
>   must be an instance of
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile, array given

I don't understand why this error is showed if `getimagesize()` doesn't use any `UploadedFile` object.

More information about the error:

[image]

Comment: try `dd($absolutePath)` and comment the result

Comment: `dd($absolutePath)` returns `"C:\htdocs\laravel-test\storage/uploads/IMG_1921.jpg"`. `gettype($absolutePath)` returns `string`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: the `app` folder is missed in the absolute path. It should be `C:\htdocs\laravel-test\storage/app/uploads/IMG_1921.jpg` instead `C:\htdocs\laravel-test\storage/uploads/IMG_1921.jpg`.

So, the solution is to add `/app` here:

```
$absolutePath = sprintf('%s/app/%s', storage_path(), $path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this inside your `foreach` loop:

```
$data = getimagesize($image->photo->path());
```